# Symlink /dev/err in docker

Tags: docker, apache, symlink

For what purpose are such symlinks set for logs in the docker? Why is it redirecting to the main process?

```
ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /app/storage/logs/apache.log
ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /dev/stderr
```

Answer (score 2):

Many software packages are designed to write their logs out to files, and don't have an obvious option to send the logs to somewhere else.  So the first thing that having this symlink does is let you configure the application to write logs to "a file", but actually have it show up on the container's stdout or stderr.

For a minimal example, you could try something like

```bash
docker run -d --name test busybox \
  sh -c 'ln -s /tmp/log.txt /proc/1/fd/1; echo "hello" > /tmp/log.txt'
docker wait test
docker logs test
docker rm test
```

In the temporary BusyBox container, we set up a symlink, and then write some text to the "log file"; since it goes to the main process's stdout, it shows up in `docker logs`.

Another common reason to do this is to give the operator the opportunity to actually write to a file, if that's what they want.  Let's consider this minimal image:

```bash
FROM busybox
RUN mkdir /logs \
 && ln -s /logs/log.txt /proc/1/fd/1
CMD echo 'hello' > /logs/log.txt
```

This is the same as the previous command but recast into image form

```shellsession
$ docker build -t log-test .
$ docker run --rm log-test
hello
```

However, we also have the option of bind-mounting a host directory to receive those logs:

```shellsession
$ mkdir logs
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD/logs:/logs" log-test
$ cat logs/log.txt
hello
```

The `docker run -v` bind-mount hides the `/logs` directory in the image, and therefore the symlink, so the `echo` command writes to an actual file, which is then visible on the host system.

I know in particular the standard HTTP-server containers are set up this way, sending the HTTP access log to stdout unless something else is configured as log storage, but it's not specific to this class of image.